# regex to match substring after nth occurence of pipe character

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to build one regex expression for the below sample text in which i need to replace the **bold** text. So far i could achieve this much
`((\|)).*(\|)` which is selecting the whole string between the first and last pip char. i am bound to use apache or java regex.

Sample String: where text length between pipes may vary

```
1.1|ProvCM|111111111111|**10.15.194.25**|10.100.10.3|10.100.10.1|docsis3.0
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To match part after `nth` occurrence of pipe you can use this regex:

```
/^(?:[^|]*\|){3}([^|]*)/
```

Here n=3

It will match `10.15.194.25` in matched group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ9yS6/2)

Comment: thanks anubhava, this matches to 10.15.194.25|10.100.10.3|10.100.10.1|docsis3.0. I just need 10.15.194.25 string out of it.

Comment: No it only matches `10.15.194.25` Did you check latest demo?

Comment: Looks okay; java: `s = s.replaceFirst("^(?:[^|]*\\|){3}([^|]*)\\|.*$", "$1");`

Comment: Finally you have it :P

Comment: This works very well! However is it easy to specify multiple occurrences using backreferences? Say you want the 1st and 3rd occurrence.

Comment: @anubhava I followed your [suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/21) on a second capture group, however note that the second set of braces cannot contain the value 0 and returns an empty capture group in such an event. Do you know why this is? `^(?:(?:[^|]*\|){0}([^|]*))(?:(?:[^|]*\|){1}([^|]*))`

Answer (score 4):

```
^((?:[^|]*\\|){3})[^|]+
```

You can use this.Replace by `$1<anything>`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/4

This here captures from `start` of string to `|` and then captures 3 such groups and stores it in `$1`.The next part of string till `|` is what you want.Now you can replace it with anything by `$1<textyouwant>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do the replacement:

```
String input = "1.1|ProvCM|111111111111|10.15.194.25|10.100.10.3|10.100.10.1|docsis3.0";
int n = 3;
String newValue = "new value";
String output = input.replaceFirst("^((?:[^|]+\\|){"+n+"})[^|]+", "$1"+newValue);
```

This builds:

```
"1.1|ProvCM|111111111111|new value|10.100.10.3|10.100.10.1|docsis3.0"
```